# Android service and native threads

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, multicast

Given the limitations that are being imposed on background services in later versions of Android, how do you accomplish the following:

1. The application's JAVA background service and the native C++ threads which are started by the JAVA background service via JNI continue to run regardless of the phone's state (screen on or off) and regardless of the application's state (activity life cycle). If an activity has been destroyed, the background service must continue to run.
2. If the user clears the application from the task list (menu button), the background service continues to run and so does the C++ threads.
3. If the user presses the menu back button, the background service continues to run and so does the C++ threads.
4. If the user navigates to the OS settings (applications) and selects FORCE CLOSE/STOP for the application, then the application AND the background service is stopped/destroyed.

One of the native threads is responsible for listening and processing UDP data via a socket that listens for multicast data. It is critical that this continues to work regardless of phone/app state (unless the app is forcefully closed).

Comment: You will probably need foreground service and return START_STICKY from the `onStartIntent()`. But whatever you do the service (maybe less likely) may get killed by the system when it's running low on resources.

Comment: Android can kill any background process when it needs resources (or it just feels like it). Threads run in processes, therefore your thread(s) can/will be killed.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your problem right, but all these points you mention, one can accomplish by using the Android Service Component like describede here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

I worked with this some time ago and it did just these points you require.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: See recent changes:  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html